# kafka broker failed to start with "Unexpected error in raft IO thread (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.ProcessTerminatingFaultHandler)" error

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a 3 node kafka broker cluster. Out of which any two nodes are coming up fine and one node randomly giving this error and not able to start.

```
# docker logs kafka-broker-1
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
Running in KRaft mode...
===> Running preflight checks ...
===> Check if /var/lib/kafka/data is writable ...
===> Running in KRaft mode, skipping Zookeeper health check...
===> Using provided cluster id mX-qLvc-T2y2OPeJ3AMRXg ...
===> Launching ...
===> Launching kafka ...
[2023-11-03 08:08:25,973] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,365] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,554] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,559] INFO [BrokerServer id=1] Transition from SHUTDOWN to STARTING (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,560] INFO [SharedServer id=1] Starting SharedServer (kafka.server.SharedServer)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,656] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-broker-logs] Loading producer state till offset 0 with message format version 2 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,657] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-broker-logs] Reloading from producer snapshot and rebuilding producer state from offset 0 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,657] INFO [LogLoader partition=__cluster_metadata-0, dir=/tmp/kraft-broker-logs] Producer state recovery took 0ms for snapshot load and 0ms for segment recovery from offset 0 (kafka.log.UnifiedLog$)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,717] INFO Initialized snapshots with IDs SortedSet() from /tmp/kraft-broker-logs/__cluster_metadata-0 (kafka.raft.KafkaMetadataLog$)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,760] INFO [raft-expiration-reaper]: Starting (kafka.raft.TimingWheelExpirationService$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,975] INFO [RaftManager id=1] Completed transition to Unattached(epoch=0, voters=[2, 3], electionTimeoutMs=1903) from null (org.apache.kafka.raft.QuorumState)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,981] INFO [kafka-1-raft-outbound-request-thread]: Starting (kafka.raft.RaftSendThread)
[2023-11-03 08:08:26,981] INFO [kafka-1-raft-io-thread]: Starting (kafka.raft.KafkaRaftManager$RaftIoThread)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,013] INFO [BrokerServer id=1] Starting broker (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,015] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,035] INFO [broker-1-ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,035] INFO [broker-1-ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,037] INFO [broker-1-ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,039] INFO [broker-1-ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,077] INFO [BrokerServer id=1] Waiting for controller quorum voters future (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,077] INFO [BrokerServer id=1] Finished waiting for controller quorum voters future (kafka.server.BrokerServer)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,091] INFO [broker-1-to-controller-forwarding-channel-manager]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,115] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,215] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,282] INFO [RaftManager id=1] Registered the listener org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader@308714136 (org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,317] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,417] INFO [MetadataLoader id=1] initializeNewPublishers: the loader is still catching up because we still don't know the high water mark yet. (org.apache.kafka.image.loader.MetadataLoader)
[2023-11-03 08:08:27,487] ERROR Encountered fatal fault: Unexpected error in raft IO thread (org.apache.kafka.server.fault.ProcessTerminatingFaultHandler)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received request or response with leader OptionalInt[1] and epoch 18 which is inconsistent with current leader OptionalInt.empty and epoch 0
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.maybeTransition(KafkaRaftClient.java:1513)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.maybeHandleCommonResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1473)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleFetchResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1071)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleResponse(KafkaRaftClient.java:1550)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.handleInboundMessage(KafkaRaftClient.java:1676)
    at org.apache.kafka.raft.KafkaRaftClient.poll(KafkaRaftClient.java:2251)
    at kafka.raft.KafkaRaftManager$RaftIoThread.doWork(RaftManager.scala:64)
    at org.apache.kafka.server.util.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.java:127)
```

The docker-compose file for broker1 is:

```
---
version: '2'
services:

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.1
    hostname: vskafka-broker-1
    container_name: kafka-broker-1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://vskafka-broker-1:29092'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '2@vskafka-controller-2:9093,3@vskafka-controller-3:9093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://vskafka-broker-1:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-broker-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'mX-qLvc-T2y2OPeJ3AMRXg'
```

With the similar configuration other two broker nodes are working fine. If will destroy and re-deploy this setup, then not necessarily the issue will come with broker1. It may be with broker2 or broker3. But issue will be with one node only and other two will work fine.

All the three controllers are UP and running and reachable from all the three broker nodes and they can talk to each other as well.

Here is the docker-compose file of controller1:

```
---
version: '2'
services:

  controller:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.1
    hostname: vskafka-controller-1
    container_name: kafka-controller-1
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@vskafka-controller-1:9093,2@vskafka-controller-2:9093,3@vskafka-controller-3:9093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'CONTROLLER://vskafka-controller-1:9093'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-controller-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'mX-qLvc-T2y2OPeJ3AMRXg'
```

Seems like something is missing at the controller level but really not sure what it could be ?

Comment: You're not using one compose file to start all the services? Also, running 3 brokers and/or controllers on one machine is still a "single point of failure" - your host+disk. So, it wont perform as well as truly separate, physical servers.

Comment: I am using 3 brokers on 3 vm and 3 controllers on another 3 vms. So total 6 vms. And yes, I am not using a single docker compose file to start all the services. All the 6 vms have their own docker compose with specific configs.

Comment: In that case, are you using Docker Swarm? What is your overlay network to resolve each of the `vskafka-controller-X` dns names? Basically, sounds like the failing machine is unable to resolve a network issue, or is otherwise having a latency or possible NTP issue... If you want to run a distributed cluster of containers, Kubernetes would be generally be better than individual Compose files, such as using k3d and Strimzi Operator, or a cloud-hosted Kubernetes like GKE

Comment: I am not using Docker Swam, but just docker via docker compose. I am using host network, not the overlay. These vms are in openstack and both DNS and NTP are resolvable. And as mentioned earlier, out of 3 broker nodes, 2 nodes are working fine always and 1 node is failing with that message. Which indicates that something is missing in the KRaft based configuration but I am not able to figure out. I may think of using them in k8s but for now want to run them in the docker compose mode to see how the performance is.

Comment: The node id must be unique between each node, and cannot overlap between brokers and controllers. You shouldn't store data in /tmp, and you want a mounted volume if you want to persist any data. Regarding networking, you've not set `network: host` in Compose, and `KAFKA_LISTENERS` should actually use `0.0.0.0` rather than the hostnames if you want it to bind to all interfaces. And you don't have 3 controller machines. You've only mentioned 1, but 3 brokers (which is a 4 node cluster)

Comment: The `KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS` must be the same across every machine as well

Comment: As mentioned in https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-metadata/config-kraft.html#server-basics document, if a server is a 'broker' only, its node ID should not appear in the 'controller.quorum.voters' list. If I am adding it, its not allowing the service to come up.

Comment: That's correct, and not what I was referring to. Your broker and controller have node id of 1. Meanwhile, a quorum should always have odd number of voters (as the docs say), otherwise you end up with split votes between your 2 listed machines (broker-1 and controller-1 are different machines, therefore need unique node ids, and broker-1 should include controller1-3 on its quorum)

Answer (score 0):

[OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer), as you recommended I changed the ID for all the brokers to 101, 102 and 103 respectively and kept the ID for controllers to 1, 2 and 3 respectively. Then added all the controllers to the quorum list:

```
KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@vskafka-controller-1:9093,2@vskafka-controller-2:9093,3@vskafka-controller-3:9093'
```

Now its working as expected.